# Golang игнорирует обработку статических файлов

Tags: html, css, golang

Всем привет
есть струтура проекта

```
-testcss
---static
------test.html
------test.css
---main.go
```

Внутри test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Data</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Внутри main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/umd/gop/testcss/"))))

    http.HandleFunc("/test/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        (w).Header().Set("Content-Type", "text;charset-utf-8")
        templ, _ := template.ParseFiles("./static/test.html")
        templ.Execute(w, nil)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil))
}
```

Внутри test.css

```
h1{
    color: springgreen;
    padding-left: 70%;
}
body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Проблема:

Если зайти на роут localhost:8181/test/ то я ожидаю там увидеть html страницу с примененными стилями css, но вижу только html страницу без применения стилей.

Как правильно подключить css чтобы golang корректно обработал и вывел страницу с применением стилей?
Гуглил и везде подход такой

```
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/umd/gop/testcss/"))))
```

Но он почему то не работает, либо я неправильно пытаюсь загрузить страницу

```
templ, _ := template.ParseFiles("./static/test.html")
templ.Execute(w, nil)
```

Но я не знаю как сделать правильно и чтобы работал css
Примечательно и возможно важно:

Если зайти на роут localhost:8181/static/ то там есть моя папка static в которую я могу перейти и открыть html документ и он отображается уже с примененными стилями. Полный роут при  этом такой

`localhost:8181/static/static/test.html`

Прошу помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Спасибо всем кто откликнется.

UPD:
Если не добавлять строку

```
(w).Header().Set("Content-Type", "text;charset-utf-8")
```

То страница загрузится без стилей и будет сообщение в консоли браузера

`Таблица стилей http://192.168.1.109:8181/test/test.css не была загружена, потому что её MIME-тип («text/html») не «text/css».`

Если в этой строке `text;charset-utf-8` поменять на `text/css;charset-utf-8` то страница загрузится и я получу содержимое файла test.html а в коноли браузера будет

`Простой текстовый документ не содержит объявления кодировки символов. Если документ содержит символы, не входящие в диапазон US-ASCII, то в некоторых конфигурациях браузера в документе будет отображён искажённый текст. Кодировка символов файла должна быть объявлена в протоколе передачи или файл должен использовать индикатор порядка байтов (BOM) в качестве сигнатуры кодировки.`

Если в этой строке `text;charset-utf-8` поменять на `text/html;charset-utf-8`  то в браузере загрузится страница корректно но без стилей а в консоли браузера будет ошибка

`Таблица стилей http://192.168.1.109:8181/test/test.css не была загружена, потому что её MIME-тип («text/html») не «text/css».`

Если оставить строку `text;charset-utf-8` то страница загружается без ошибок но без стилей

Comment: Вы же сами написали - все, что приходит по адресу http.HandleFunc("/test/" получает в ответ test.html.

Comment: @KoVadim
Вот и я говорю, что не могу понять как сделать чтобы эти файлы оба загружались при заходе на /test/

Comment: @KoVadim
Вот что мне приходит в голову но конечно же не работает templ, _ := template.ParseFiles("./static/test.html", "./static/test.css")

Comment: можно в html просто прописать правильный путь к css - где то такой ../static/static/test.css

Comment: ну вот жеж подстава. Я какие только пути не пробовал и именно этот путь не попробовал, а оказалось все так просто!!)))Спасибо вам большое,как всегда помогаете)

Comment: @KoVadim
А вы случайно не знаете куда копнуть чтобы узнать как сделать так чтобы тот кто посещает сайт не мог попасть в папку static?

Comment: для этого точно нужно убрать строку с `http.Handle("/static/", `. Но тогда css не будет работать